# Android gap above PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagertitlestrip

I'm having an issue with my layout where there is a gap between the PagerTitleStrip and the ActionBar. Here's my layout and how it looks, it seems to display fine in the preview window but not on my device.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/fuelActivityViewPager"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        style="@style/titleStrip"
        android:id="@+id/pagerTitleStrip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

[Gap..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KVxl.png)

Comment: Could you post the contents of @style/titleStrip?

Comment: `<style name="titleStrip">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">top</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/button_margin</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorMaterialDarkOrange</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>`

Comment: the setContentView is set to use the layout above. I've tried nesting it in a linear layout as well.

Comment: remove padding from style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In my activity I had the action bar set to navigation tabs mode and it is deprecated/not available with the pager title strip. Once I removed it the space went away.